# Video gets played all by itself when the website loads

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have encountered a very weird problem with fancybox modal that whenever
my website gets load then the video gets played itself which should played in a modal when
someone clicks on the specific link. Video will get loaded after around 5 mins all by itself.

NOTE:I am using chrome and on it when site opens i dont click anything on the site leave the site as it is and after around five minutes a video gets played all by itself .

kindly let me know how can i fix this issue.
Thanks,

**Code part related to video:**

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="divVideo" style="background:url(./images/blackbg.png);width:850px;height:480px;">
        <p>
            <iframe id="iframe-video" style="margin-top:40px;" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/39892976?api=1&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ff9933&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=0&amp;player_id=iframe-video" width="670" height="380" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
            <div class="fs16" style="margin-top:-15px;color:#5f5f60;">
                Having problems watching? Switch to non-HD
            </div>

        </p>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? On Firefox the video only plays when I hit the "click play to watch video" button. You can try to change autoplay to 0 in the iframe (where you embed the video) but if you do that, the video won't automatically play when the modal box opens.

Comment: Also...<div> tags inside of <p> tags == no bueno.

Comment: @ComputerArts the autoplay option seems to me quite a one approach to resolve this issue. I am using chrome and on it when site opens i dont click anything on the site leave the site as it is and after around five minutes a video gets played all by itself .

Comment: @soft genic K. I just let your sit sit open in 7 -- Browsers -> IE8, IE9, Android 2.2, iOS5, Chrome (latest distribution), Safari (latest distribution) and FireFox (latest distribution) it's been 10 minutes, not one video has attempted to play. Also, I do not see any console requests attempting to load the video, either.

Comment: I dont know why its not happening at your end. I swear its happening at my end and i am clueless about it , kindly let me know if you think something i should fix in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `autoplay=1` to `autoplay=0` in your iframe url. As long as you have the iFrame on you page at load (existing in the html rather than added later with javascript), and you have `autoplay=1` in the url, Vimeo will start playing instantly.

If you are looking for the video to autoplay when the user opens the modal, then you will have a more complex solution, because you will need `autoplay=1` in the url, but NOT have it in the html and only in your javascript file.